# trouble connecting cefsharp browser with nancy hosted angular web app

Tags: c#, angularjs, wpf, cefsharp

I have a [Cefsharp](http://cefsharp.github.io/) chromium browser and a simple web application hosted with [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) on a local port built into a wpf application. I would like to use angular with my web application, but I am struggling to change variables inside the angular scope.

Directly on the angular page, everything works perfectly. However, when I try to cross the gap between C# and JS, it partially fails. When I fire the call off from C#, the alert windows still appear and the value of `report_type` does appear to change in the alert box. However, in the `ng-switch`, nothing is updated. It's almost as if I am not accessing the correct scope when firing the call from C#... yet if that were the case, the methods in the angular scope shouldn't be callable from C#.

in C#, I call this:

```
private void GIS_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.report_browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("ext_switch_gis();");
}
```

On the served web page:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.switch_gis = function switch_gis() {
    alert("begin switch gis");
    $scope.report_type = "gis";
    alert("end switch gis");
    alert("report value is: " + $scope.report_type);
  }

  $scope.switch_bar = function switch_bar() {
    alert("begin switch bar");
    $scope.report_type = "bar";
    alert("end switch bar");
    alert("report value is: " + $scope.report_type);
  }

  $scope.mytest = function mytest(words) {
    alert(words);
  }

  $scope.switch_bar();
});

function ext_switch_gis() {
  var outside_scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('myAppDiv')).scope();
  outside_scope.mytest("Beginning of external js call!");
  outside_scope.switch_gis();
  outside_scope.mytest("End of external js call!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myAppDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="report_switch_div" ng-switch="report_type">
    <div ng-switch-when="bar">
      <h1>bar</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="gis">
      <h1>gis</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <h1>Select a report type</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="switch_gis()">gis test</button>
  <button ng-click="switch_bar()">bar test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. It seems that when invoking a JS function externally, it may often be necessary to use `$apply` to make sure the "magic" behind angular that allows for 2 way bindings continues to take effect.

This article was very helpful to me: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

The actual code change I made was this:

```
$scope.switch_gis = function switch_gis() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
       $scope.report_type = "gis";
    });
}
```